# JPA (hibernate) relation OneToMany with date

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I need to create hibernate relation one to many between Department and Person (one Department has many persons).

The problem is that I want to **maintain time validity**. Without ORM (hibernate) it is easy to select persons of particular department at specified date:

```
select * from Person where department_id = ? and ? between validFrom and validTill
```

**How can I do it with JPA hibernate?**

```
class Department {
  Long id;
  String code; 
  String name;
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "departmentId")
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
}
```

```
class Person {
  Long id;
  String name;
  String surname;
  Date validFrom;
  Date validTill;
}
```

And how to do it if Department is time valid too?

```
select P.* from Person P, Deparment d 
where d.code = ? and 
p.department_id = d.department_id and 
? between d.validFrom and d.validTill and 
? between p.validFrom and p.validTill
```

All records with same deparment.code is one department.

Comment: Why didn't you let Eclipse do the annotations for you?

Comment: Because it is not standard annotation so Eclipse is not able to do it :)

Comment: [It was answered here.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594812/hibernate-relation-onetomany-with-non-unique-key/7603339#7603339

Answer (score 1):

You do it in JPA the same way that you're doing it with SQL. Just make it a JPQL query rather that a SQL query:

```
select p from Person p
inner join p.department d
where d.code = :departmentCode
and :today between d.validFrom and d.validTill 
and :today between p.validFrom and p.validTill
```

Comment: How can I define the relation (annotation)? It is possible to use EAGER or LAZY loading for specified date? eg. I will load departments and I want to load set of person in every department at specified date. Question edited - added relation.

Comment: To be able to use my query, you would need to define the inverse assoctaion (a department property in the Person entity). But you could also write a different query (starting from department and joining on d.persons). Every association can be made lazy of eager. A date is not an association. You could mark a basic field lazy, but It's generally not useful.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand you. I have twou classes (Department, Person) as above. I read one department. Hibernate generate query and loads only department. Then I access persons collection (iterate or query size). Hibernate proxy will generate query and fill persons with all person in department. The query is generated by hibernate, how can I add the date parameter? If I fill the persons collection manually there will be problem at persist(Department) which should before persist changed persons ... (cascade.persist)

Comment: When you'll access the persons collection, you'll get all the persons of the department, whether they're valid or not. Up to you to provide a method which only returns the valid persons at a given date. You could also use a filter on the collection to only return the valid persons at the current date. See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-filters

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way how to handle second problem (department is time valid too)? I need define relation where child (Person) will have non unique parent key (Department.code) - in plain sql I can do it as I described in last query statement in question.

Comment: Same answer: use a specific method (getValidDepartment()), or a specific query (as shown in my answer), or a filter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3887/discussion-between-vlada-and-jb-nizet)

Comment: I can use manyToMany but it's not exactly what I need. If I add a person to department DEP1 I have to associate it manually with all departments with code DEP1. If I sometime in the future add new department with code DEP1 I will have to associate the new department with all Persons belonging to DEP1. Because it use join table which refers PK's of both tables. Is there a way how to set relation which use department.code directly?