# Hibernate relation OneToMany with non unique key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I am not able to describe my problem, I try it again with example:

I have two entities (tables): **Department** and **Person**. Both tables have a field *CODE* which is **not unique**.

How can I **define** manyToMany **bidirectional relations** between these tables?

1. Departmen has collection Persons which returns all entities with Person.CODE eq Department.CODE
2. Partner has collection Departments which returns all entities with Department.CODE eq Partner.CODE

I need the relation definition - no sql or hpql query.

--------- Original question -------

I need to create hibernate relation one to many between Department and Person (one Department has many persons). Department and persons has time validity (validFrom, validTill)

```
class Department {
  Long id;
  String code; 
  String name;
  Date validFrom;
  Date validTill;
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "departmentId")
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  private Set<Person> persons = new HashSet<Person>();
}
```

```
 class Person {
      Long id;
      String name;
      String surname;
      Date validFrom;
      Date validTill;
    }
```

Without ORM (hibernate) it is easy to select persons of particular department at specified date:

```
select P.* from Person P, Deparment d 
where d.code = ? and 
p.department_id = d.department_id and 
? between d.validFrom and d.validTill and 
? between p.validFrom and p.validTill
```

**The relation has to use non unique key (CODE) instead of department ID.**

Is it possible to do something similar with hibernate?

I don't need separated objects and construct queries myself.

I want use all feature which ORM offers (lazy loading, cascase persist ...)

Comment: You want to retrieve only data, or when insert a new department with the same code as an existing update all relations?

Comment: Both. Retrieve data and When I insert a new department I want to assign to it all persons belonging to department with the CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

First off, you mention that you want to use all features which ORM offers.  If this is the case then you need to use a schema that Hibernate is friendly toward.  There are annotations available in both the JPA persistence API and with Hibernate-specific API that allow you to more easily work with 'legacy' databases.  But if you want full and correct Hibernate use, then you have to design your schema according to what Hibernate expects.

You can do what you are asking in this case by using a join formula instead of a join column for your relationships.  The join formula is a valid SQL fragment (which may reduce portability).  I've left the actual SQL out in the example below.

```
public class Person {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinFormula("sql fragment")
    private List<Department> departments;
    ...
}

public class Department {
    ...
    @OneToMany
    @JoinFormula("sql fragment")
    private List<Person> people;
    ...
}
```

You should also consider treating code as a Hibernate object:

```
@Embeddable
public class Code {
    ...
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 20)
    private String code;
    ...
}
```

Rather than just a string so that the use of a code in entity relationships is more effectively managed by the Hibernate persistence context and the row mapping process.

Lastly, consider actually mapping the relationship between Person and Department as a join table in your schema.  You'd then be able to take advantage of the `@ManyToMany` and `@JoinTable` annotations to do actual schema-based relationships in your entities.

Comment: I am sorry. I don't understand. oneToMany and ManyToOne relation uses primary and foreign key. But I don't need this. My problem is that I need relation without PK-FK.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show use of Hibernate relationships without 'real' foreign keys.

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation. Can you please provide the sql fragment for joining two tables using CODE?

Comment: Maybe you can recommend better way. I need this for support of data planning. Eg. User can prepare several records which will be valid at specified interval (ValidFrom, ValidTill). There can be only one valid record at a time, the interval doesn't have to be continuous.  Example: I have department AAA which is valid from 1.1.2010 to 31.12.2099. Somewhere in future I want to rename department I change validTill of existing record to 31.12.2012 and create new one with new name and valid from 1.1.2013 till 31.12.2099. to be able maintain person assignment I have to add validity to join table too

Comment: *"But if you want full and correct Hibernate use, then you have to design your schema according to what Hibernate expects."* Your schema design should be independent of the ORM.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a [Filter](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html). It allows you to add that check to every query you do, or disable it if you like.

Example:

```
<class name="Department" ...>
    ...
    <many-to-one name="person" column="person_id" class="Person"/>
    <property name="validFrom" type="date" column="validFrom"/>
    <property name="validTill" type="date" column="validTill"/>
    <property name="code" type="string" column="code"/>
    ...
    <!--
        Note that this assumes non-terminal records have an eff_end_dt set to
        a max db date for simplicity-sake
    -->
    <filter name="effectiveDate"
            condition="code = :code and :asOfDate BETWEEN validFrom and validTill"/>
</class>
```

Regards.

Comment: Filter doesn't work fine :( Because with this annotation is relation between primary key (department) and foreign key (person - departmentId). But I need person reference non unique department "code"

Comment: That was just an example, but it fits in the description of your problem. You can place whatever in the filter (sql with named parameters)

Comment: ... or one can use HQL or dynamically add a Criteria.

Comment: Please can you provide annotation for relation between Department and Person where Persons refers non unique keys in Department? I can you manyToMany but when I add new Person I would like to associate it with all departments (with same code) without generating records to join table.

Comment: I can use manyToMany but it's not exactly what I need. If I add a person to department DEP1 I have to associate it manually with all departments with code DEP1. If I sometime in the future add new department with code DEP1 I will have to associate the new department with all Persons belonging to DEP1. Because it use join table which refers PK's of both tables. Is there a way how to set relation which use department.code directly?

Comment: You can add a formula to the tag defining the relation.

Comment: Can you provide example please?

Comment: sure, please add your mappings

Comment: I have add mapping to question. It is oneToMany which use primary and foreign key. I need another mapping (manyToMany?) which allows me to maintaint time validity and it should use department.code as described above