# create a new junction table to reflect two column primary key in one of the joined tables

Tags: mysql, sql

In a MYSQL database, I need to create a new junction table for a many to many relationship to reflect the fact that one of the tables in the relationship has a two-column composite primary key.  **How do I write the SQL to accomplish this?**

Here is the current table structure:

```
wordkeys  
    keyword (pk)

description  
    id  
    effectiveTime  
    other columns
    primary key (id, effectiveTime)  

oldjunction  
    keyword (fk to wordkeys)  
    descriptionid (fk to description)//this needs to change to add effectiveTime  
    primary key (keyword, descriptionid)//this needs to change to add effectiveTime  

newjunction  (need to create this table as a function of the others above)  
    keyword (fk to wordkeys table)  
    descriptionid  
    effectiveTime  
    primary key (keyword, descriptionid, effectiveTime)
    foreign key (descriptionid, effectiveTime) to description table
```

The SQL needs to accomplish the following:

```
FOR EACH row in oldjunction
    1.) get all the values of effectiveTime associated with the given descriptionid from that row  
    2.) FOR EACH value of effectiveTime from step 1, create a new row in newjunction table
```

---

EDIT:

---

In response to the comments, I am adding more information as follows:

I need help translating the `FOR EACH` component of my original posting above into SQL syntax. This will need to create the `newjunction` table.  The reason we need the `newjunction` table is that `descriptionid` alone does not uniquely identify individual rows in the `description` table.  Instead, we need the combination of `descriptionid` and `effectiveTime` in order to get a unique identifier for each row in the `description` table.  Does this clarify the problem?

Comment: Is the main problem you're facing with the compound key? How would you write the SQL you're looking for with the old, non-compound key? Should be easy to take it from there.

Comment: What have you got so far, and is causing you problems?  You seem to have started the problem decomposition alright.  ...Although, I'd be hesitant to put `effectiveTime` in the cross-reference table.  What are trying to accomplish by including it?  Putting _all_ rows into the new table provides the same relationship as you get with just linking to `id`.  If you're trying to say that the relationship was keyed by the time, then you need to remove `effectiveTime` from the `description` table.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Please see the addendum to my original posting above.  I am getting problems because `descriptionid` does not uniquely identify each row in the `description` table.  Also, I need help translating the pseudocode into the SQL required to create the `newjunction` table.  I don't know how to translate all the `FOR EACH` stuff into sql.  Can you help?

Comment: @JanickBernet I am online and able to respond promptly if you are willing to help me now.

Comment: No, what I'm getting at is: The only reason to include a column in a cross-reference table is it makes a difference _in the relationship_.  It doesn't matter about uniqueness in either table.  Which is why I'm concerned - you're bringing in _every_ row, which means that `effectiveTime` isn't really useful information there.  Moving forward, will you bring all new instances of `effective time` into the join table?  Then it's pointless to include it in the cross-reference table.  What benefit are you trying to achieve by doing this?  You don't have to reference all columns in a foreign key...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse This table underlies a spring-mvc web application that uses hibernate and jpa.  I have been getting errors related to the app finding more than one record in the `description` table for a given `descriptionid`.  I am trying this approach so that hibernate/jpa can see both of the fields that together comprise the key.  There are other fields in the `description` table.  I just summarized them as `other columns` above rather than listing them all.  Does this new info help you give more feedback?

Comment: Then what you have is a JPA/Hibernate problem, not an SQL problem.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594812/hibernate-relation-onetomany-with-non-unique-key) appears promising.  If you still need help, post a new question asking about your ORM problem.  The additional columns are unimportant - it's a regular [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem.  Continuing on in this manner is going to be papering over a glaring hole.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Thank you very much.  I will look into this when I next log in.  If I need to post a separate question, I will do so, and then message you.  Have a wonderful evening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I gathered I think what you're looking for is this:

```
INSERT INTO newjunction 
SELECT o.keyword, d.id, d.effectiveTime
  FROM description d
  JOIN oldjunction o
    ON o.descriptionid = d.id
```

Also I think `newjunction` is missing an FK to `wordkeys` table.

Comment: Yes, I meant o, fixed.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer because the query resulted in a 20% increase in the number of rows in the junction table, which I assume means all of that the unique rows of each table are now referenced by the join table.  I will, however, look into Clockwork-Muse's suggestion when I next log on.  He seems to be saying that this approach is flawed.